# Additional check in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was given a task to write a **Prolog** program that would put given **domino pieces** in a **loop**. I figured I would first put them in order and then check for answers where the **last number** and the **first number** would **match**.
However, the predicate responsible for the latter task *(domino_order2)* is giving me some trouble. Any ideas on how I could implement this last check?
Thank you in advance!

```
domino_order2(L1, L2):-
    end_match(L2,L2),
    domino_order(L1, L2).

end_match([X-Y | _],L2):-
    %last(L2,X).
    append(_,[Y-X],L2).

domino_order(L1, L2) :-
    domino_order(L1, _, L2).

domino_order([], _, []) :- !.
domino_order(In, X, [X-Y | Out]) :-
    select(Piece, In, Remaining),
    swap_or_not(Piece, X-Y),
    domino_order(Remaining, Y, Out).

swap_or_not(X-Y, X-Y).
swap_or_not(X-Y, Y-X).
```

Desired outcome:

```
?- domino_order2([4-3,3-5,5-8,8-4],Out).
Out = [4-3, 3-5, 5-8, 8-4] ;
Out = [3-4, 4-8, 8-5, 5-3] ;
Out = [3-5, 5-8, 8-4, 4-3] ;
Out = [5-3, 3-4, 4-8, 8-5] ;
Out = [5-8, 8-4, 4-3, 3-5] ;
Out = [8-5, 5-3, 3-4, 4-8] ;
Out = [8-4, 4-3, 3-5, 5-8] ;
Out = [4-8, 8-5, 5-3, 3-4].
?- domino_order2([4-3,3-5,5-8,8-5],Out).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewrite which matches the worded spec and desired output (but not the precise order of the output):

```
domino_order(Lst, Ord) :-
    (Lst1 = Lst ; reverse_dominos(Lst, Lst1)),
    domino_order_left_to_right(Lst1, Ord).


reverse_dominos(Lst, RevLst) :-
    reverse_dominos_(Lst, [], RevLst).

reverse_dominos_([], RevLst, RevLst).
reverse_dominos_([X-Y|Tail], SoFar, RevLst) :-
    % Reverse the numbers and their position
    reverse_dominos_(Tail, [Y-X|SoFar], RevLst).


domino_order_left_to_right(Lst, Lst1) :-
    % Get a starting point in Lst
    append([Before, [Start], After], Lst),
    % Rearrange the list
    append([[Start], After, Before], Lst1).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findall(Ord, domino_order([4-3,3-5,5-8,8-4], Ord), Ords)).
% 244 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 1475890 Lips)
Ords = [[4-3,3-5,5-8,8-4],[3-5,5-8,8-4,4-3],[5-8,8-4,4-3,3-5],[8-4,4-3,3-5,5-8],[4-8,8-5,5-3,3-4],[8-5,5-3,3-4,4-8],[5-3,3-4,4-8,8-5],[3-4,4-8,8-5,5-3]].
```